# Registering Users in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

So the problem is with registering user.When check the Network in the dev tools I can see user being created, but it is not redirecting me to the home, and when I check in the Applications to see if there are any cookies I cant see any. Why is it not pushing me to the home. If someone could help me I would be grateful.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


const Register = ({ history }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmpassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const registerHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const config = {
      header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    if (password !== confirmpassword) {
      setPassword("");
      setConfirmPassword("");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setError("");
      }, 5000);
      return setError("Passwords do not match");
    }

    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register",
        {
          username,
          email,
          password,
        },
        
        config
        
      );
    
      localStorage.setItem("authToken", data.token);

      history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        setError(error.response.data.error);
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
         setError("");
      }, 5000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="register-screen">
      <form onSubmit={registerHandler} className="register-screen__form">
        <h3 className="register-screen__title">Register</h3>
        {error && <span className="error-message">{error}</span>}
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name">Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            required
            id="name"
            placeholder="Enter username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            required
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            required
            id="password"
            autoComplete="true"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            required
            id="confirmpassword"
            autoComplete="true"
            placeholder="Confirm password"
            value={confirmpassword}
            onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Register
        </button>

        <span className="register-screen__subtext">
          Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: Are you CORS crossposting between domains? If this is so, your cookies set on your `localhost:5000` won't be available on the domain you host your react app. Cookies set on a domain are never available on other domains (this would basically break the whole internet security).

Comment: do I just have to uninstall it

Comment: Wiktor Zychla@ still not redirecting me to the home

Answer (score 0):

Is CORS enabled on the server-side? If not, you need to enable Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) on your server. Assuming that you are using express for the backend. You will need to register a middleware for that. You can use this npm package for that: [https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html]
and register the middleware by calling this function: app. use(cors()). If you are using a different stack for the backend you need to enable CORS by using some package or there can be built-in support for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
},
```

try this one

Comment: You should always explain your answer.